# Get the filename of the first attachment in a list item

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, attachments, image

I have a custom view form for my list.  The form needs to display the contents of the list item as well as the photo that is attached to the list item.  Currently I am having the end user copy and paste the filename into a separate column and using that to complete the src for the `<img>` tag.

I have used the following code to display the image on the .aspx form:

`<img border="0" src="/Lists/Barring Records/Attachments/{@ID}/{@photo}" style="max-width: 1000px; max-height: 600px;"/>`

where `@ID` is the list item ID and `@photo` is the copy-and-paste filename.  This works  but is awful for the end user.

Is there a way to find and reference the first attachment for the list item and insert it where the `{@photo}` goes?  I do not care about any other attachments but the first.  I would prefer to do this on the form page, but can put the code elsewhere if instructed.

I have SharePoint Foundations 2010

Answer (score 1):

you can grab the attatchment name with this function:

```
function getAttachment(itemId, listName) {

  var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
  var requestUri = url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items(" +   itemId + ")/AttachmentFiles";
  var str = "";

   // execute AJAX request
   $.ajax({
      url: requestUri,
      type: "GET",
      headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
      async: false,
      success: function (data) {
         for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {
             str = data.d.results[i].ServerRelativeUrl;
         }
     },
     error: function (err) {
         //alert(err);
     }
  });
  window.open(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Colbs, your code should work in sp13, however, for sp10, it is not the answer.

@Ryan, in my opinion, you might prefer a codeless solution, right? you can use asset library, for end users, they create folder instead of list item, the pictures uploaded in a folder will display in thumbnail view, users can easily preview them when open a folder in this library.