# Can we use javascript to display attachment filename of a list item?

Tags: javascript

I just need the attachment filename of list item to display in a display page, not the link.  Let's say List name: MyList and item ID: 1

When I try to use the ajax and I did some test.  Somehow it stop into the ajax function.  Do I need to do anything in the server to make it work?

Here is my testing code:

```
<script>
  var attachments = function(url, name, ID) {

  alert(url);
  alert(name+':'+ID);
  var urlstr = url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + name + "')/items(" + ID + ")/AttachmentFiles/";
  alert(urlstr);
  document.getElementById('attachments').innerHTML = '<table><tr><td>'+url+'</td></tr></table>';
 //It stops working right here. everything is working above this point.

 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: urlstr,
    headers: {
      "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
      "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
    },
    success: function(data) {
                alert(ID);
    },
    error: function() {alert(ID)}
  });

};


  </script>
  </td></tr></table>
<button type='button' onclick="attachments('MySite', 'MyList', 1 )"> Get Files </button>
<div id="attachments" ></div>
```

Comment: I found something like this.  Could anyone told me that how I can call this function to display the filename?
http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/126149/get-the-filename-of-the-first-attachment-in-a-list-item

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: Where do you want to display this custom link? On the display form, edit form, or in search results somewhere?

Comment: I just create a standard custom display form in SP 2013.

Comment: If you want to use a custom display form, take a look at option 2 in my answer.

Comment: Instead of putting code throughout the comments, why not update your question with more details including what you have tried, what research you have already done, etc.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1: Search Display Template**

If you are using SP2013 and want to display the list attachments in search results, try this article:

[Solution to displaying attachments for a list item in a search result](http://techmikael.blogspot.ca/2014/04/solution-to-displaying-attachments-for.html)

> There’s an undocumented managed property named `LinkOfficeChild` which gives us exactly what we need. If you split the value on line break you will get the count.

Instead of getting the count, get the filenames by splitting the array items. Here is some code I am using on my site:

```
// check for attachments
if (ctx.CurrentItem.LinkOfficeChild) {
    var attachmentLinks = ctx.CurrentItem.LinkOfficeChild.split(/\n+/);
    var numberOfLinks = attachmentLinks.length;
    var linkMarkup = "<ul>";
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfLinks; i++) {
        var filename = attachmentLinks[i].substring(attachmentLinks[i].lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        linkMarkup = linkMarkup + "<li><a href='" + attachmentLinks[i] + "'>" + filename + "</a></li>";
    }
    linkMarkup = linkMarkup + "</ul>";
}
```

For more basic information see [Introduction to display templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj945138(v=office.15).aspx)

**Option 2: Customise Display Form**

If you want to get the filenames on the display form using JavaScript, try something like this:

```
var attTable = document.getElementById('idAttachmentsTable');
if (attTable) {
  var attachments = attTable.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (var i = 0; i < attachments.length; i++) {
    var filename = attachments[i].innerText;
    // do something with the filename
  }
}
```

I grabbed `idAttachmentsTable` by inspecting the OOTB display form.

Comment: Is there anyway without install any additional package in the SP? Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by package? The snippet I provided would go in a custom display template which you can upload with design manager.

Comment: I'm assuming you are running 2013 but perhaps that is wrong. Please answer these other comments so we can better help you.

Comment: It is Sharepoint 2013.

Comment: How can I use the option 1 and how to put it into the Script tag?  How can I call it from the regular tag? Please give me the detail.  Thanks!

Comment: Check my updated answer for a link to display template introduction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use rest api to get just the name of all the attachments.

You need to paste the function in the script tag in your page, and put the html snippet anywhere you wish to show your attachments.

Function to get attachments, this goes into your script tag :

```
var attachments = function(url, name, ID) {

  alert('Ji')

  $.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + name + "')/items(" + id + ")/AttachmentFiles/",
    header: {
      "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
      "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
    },
    success: function(data) {
      var str = '<table>';
      for (var i = data.d.results.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        //iterates through all the attachments

        str += "<tr><td>" + data.d.results[i].FileName + "</td></tr>";
      }

      str += '</table>';

      //now the variable str has all the filenames in table structure. 
      //We now append this complete structure into a div with id attachments

      document.getElementById('attachments').innerHTML = str;

    },
    error: function() {}
  });

};
```

The html will look something like this, repalace the url, name and id as you see fit :

```
button type='button' onclick="attachments('http://abc.sharepoint.com', 'List1', 12 )"> Get Files </button>
<div id="attachments" ></div>
```

This function on resolution returns an array of files. You can iterate and get just file names like for example - `data.d.results[0].FileName` will give you file name of the first file.

Comment: I am sorry. I am a dummy. Could you tell me how can we use the function? For example,
How to create something like this in javascript. 
-----<td>filename.ext</td>------

-----------------------------------
<td>
<script>
attachment(<name>, <ID>).then(

        //success - promise gets resolved 
        function() { return data[0].FileName },

        //error 
        function() { alert('error')};

     )
</script>
</td>

Comment: Can you write some simple code to write the filename without calling the function?
So I can put the code direct into <script></script> and return it in the browser.  Many thanks!

Comment: I have simplified the above code as much as I possibly can. You can now put the function in a `<script>` tag, and then use the html snippet anywhere in your page to use the functionality

Comment: Thanks for your update.  Now I can use the script in my page. But after I debugged, I found the $.ajax(); is functioning.  How can I know? I put alert('test'); inside each success: function(data) {} and error: function() {}.  It did not pop up any Alert. 
But when I put "http://abc.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List1')/items(12)/AttachmentFiles/", it returned the item info on the browser. 
Do you have any hint?  
Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Make sure you have a reference to jquery before your script tag . Add `<script type="text\javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js">` before the tag containing the function.  `abc.sharepoint.com/` is just a dummy, you need to put the site url that you are querying from in order to use it. Also replace  `list1` with list name that you want to query from and `12` with id of the list item item that you want to query the associated files from

Comment: yes, I put my own site and list for testing.  But cannot put the it over here.  I try some testing and find out the javascript was stopped at $.ajax.  I put the alert() for debug the function. It just don't run $.ajax.

Comment: <script type="text\javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"> 
  </script> 
  <script>  
  var attachments = function(url, name, ID)  ..... </script>

Comment: Am I doing right?

Comment: yes. It doesn't work yet?

Comment: I just repost the question.  It stop working right at AJAX function.  Moreover, I have to change "id" in the urlstr string to "ID" to make it run.

Comment: ok. All the best.

Comment: Now, I found the error code:
SCRIPT5009: '$' is undefined it is near the ajax.
Why "$" is undefined?  How can I need to define $? 
This is the main cause that I cannot run ajax function.
Thanks!

Comment: I found the issue.  "text\javascript" should be written as "text/javascript".  Now, I can make it work.  Thanks for everyone!

Comment: Oops.. I got to learn something today :)